ReactSelect - Search doesn't work with custom ValueContainer
Based on this question I created a custom ReactSelect where I can show only 2 selected value and introduce a "+ n other" badge in order to keep everything in one row.
I would like the component to be searchable, and this works normally until I select 2 values, than it doesn't work. Looking the HTML, it seems the input isn't even rendered when i select those 2 values.
Can you help me?
Here my code and two screenshots of HTML. No other customization are made on the ReactSelect component. I tried to add <components.Input> inside <components.ValueContainer> but i have 2 inputs with 0,1 value selected, 1 input with 2+ values selected but behind the chips and still not working.
I'm under typescript, with react 18.2.0, node 20.5.9, react-select 5.7.7.
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactSelect, { components } from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "1", label: "uno" },
  { value: "2", label: "due" },
  { value: "3", label: "tre" },
  { value: "4", label: "quattro" },
  { value: "5", label: "cinque" },
];

const Index = () => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<{ value: string; label: string }[]>([]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-[500px] mt-10 ml-10">
        <ReactSelect
          isMulti
          isSearchable
          hideSelectedOptions={false}
          options={options}
          value={selectedOptions}
          onChange={(newValue) => setSelectedOptions([...newValue])}
          noOptionsMessage={() => <>Nessun risultato</>}
          components={{
            ValueContainer: ({ getValue, children, ...props }) => {
              let maxToShow = 2;
              var length = getValue().length;
              let displayChips = React.Children.toArray(children).slice(
                0,
                maxToShow
              );
              let shouldBadgeShow = length > maxToShow;
              let displayLength = length - maxToShow;

              return (
                <components.ValueContainer
                  getValue={getValue}
                  {...props}>

                  {/* Render the selected options */}
                  {displayChips}

                  {/* Render badges */}
                  {shouldBadgeShow && (
                    <div className="text-[12px] ml-auto text-primary-blue underline">
                      {"+" + displayLength + "altri"}
                    </div>
                  )}

                </components.ValueContainer>
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mt-12 ml-12">{JSON.stringify(selectedOptions)}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;


one value selected, search is working 3 values selected, search is not working (no input in DOM)
